# The best way to do overlay

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<div id="main">
    <div>TITLE</div>
    <div>BODY</div>
    <div>COMMENT</div>
    <div><textarea></textarea></div>
</div>
<button>overlay</button>

#main {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

live: http://jsfiddle.net/9DLyE/1/

How is the best way to do overlay in jQuery? If i click on button overlay then i would like overlay (same as fancybox) all div#main, for example background-color: blue and transparency 0.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `position:absolute` to place the overlay div and use `jquery toggle` to show it.

**CSS**

```
#main {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: yellow;
    position:relative
}
#overlay{
    background:rgba(0, 84, 214, 0.5);
    height:100%; width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0; left:0;
    display:none
}
```

**jquery**

```
$('button').click(function(){
    $('#overlay').toggle();
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/9DLyE/6/)

Comment: `position:fixed` is better.

Comment: @Kolink Actually NO. fixed position always points to the browser not to the parent element

Comment: OP is asking for "same as fancybox", suggesting they want to overlay the entire browser viewport.

Comment: @Kolink Look at this line 'i would like overlay (same as fancybox) all div#main' Which means the main div

Answer (score 0):

What you have tried..??try to put click event like

```
$('button').on('click',function(){
   //Do your stuff
});
```

Try this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/9DLyE/2/)

Comment: This change background-color, but i will keep original background and add on this overlay with z-index on max.